# AdMobs not showing in android apk

Tags: admob, ads, adsense

I have a problem , my ads aren't showing in my apk. My ads were running for a week in a perfect way, but suddenly nothing is showing in the ad box, and the earnings are 0. Do you know any Solution about this?

Comment: ads were showing on the release apk, but after 3-4 days they disappeared, only shows blank spaces.

Comment: I wrote an issue about this, may give you a hint,  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30773